# PHP instance method vs. variable

Tags: php, oop, instance-methods

It is possible that the two code below gives different results?

This runs as i expected:

```
$message = new Message();
$cond = $message->getMessage();
$helper->log($cond);
if(!empty($cond)){
  // do my stuff
}
```

This is where i start wondering why gave me different result:

```
$message = new Message();
$helper->log($message->getMessage());
if(!empty($message->getMessage())){
  // do my stuff
}
```

All i modified is that i changed `$cond` variable to `$message->getMessage()`.

This is the constrictor of the Message Class:

```
class Message {
  private $input;
  private $message;

public function Message()
{
  $this->input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
  // ...
  $this->message = $this->input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
  //...
}
}
```

And this is the getter method:

```
public function getMessage()
{
  return $this->message;
}
```

Comment: What is the "different result" that you saw in the second case?

Comment: With same circumstances first code run into the if statement, but second doesn't. And the same is the behavior in the log function too.

Comment: Is `getMessage()` idempotent?

Comment: So the only difference is that in first code getMessage method called once. Does this method changes the state of $message object ? I would look at realization of getMessage method.

Comment: I updated my question with the relevant part of the constructor and the getter method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check your php_error_log.

PHP's [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) does not support expressions when you're using PHP version < 5.5:

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will
>   result in a parse error. [...]

Possibly this is the resaon why the code inside your if statement isn't reached.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with `$message->getMessage() != ""` it's working corrertly.

Comment: If this is your problem, you should consider upgrading your PHP version, because it should work in PHP 5.5, which is the lowest currently supported version. If you're on a version older than 5.5, you should be urgently considering upgrading.